# Adding files to Installshield cabinet

Tags: addition, installshield, cab

I am trying to add a file (licence information) to a several Installshield installers, to save storing the files seperately.

I have downloaded InstallShield 2012 trial, but don't have the project files.

Is this possible (no matter how hard the steps required)?

Comment: A lot of this depends on project type and build configuration. For instance, uncompressed MSI files are (relatively) easy to modify, while anything compressed into a setup.exe is fairly hard to modify.

Comment: @MichaelUrman These are "data.cab"'s I am trying to add files to.

Comment: There used to be a standalone tool for modifying IS' CAB files but I think it was discontinued after IS X. I also vaguely recall reading something that IS CAB files are not exactly like MS CAB files but that could be my creeping decrepitude.

Comment: @DaveE - This is my understanding from research also (MS Cab is differently structered to IS Cab's). I have tried a few standalone tools, which are probably what you describe, as I get the distinct impression that the errors they give me indicate they can't open a later IS produced CAB.

Comment: @MichaelUrman - Any advise for working with data.cab's? Also, is there anyway to tell what version of InstallShield created the cab's?

Answer (score 0):

You can reverse engineer .cab and .msi files very easily.

As a first step; see what you can do using 7-zip.

I'm not a 100% sure if the hashes are checked, if not you should just be able to insert/modify the LICENSE within the CAB directly, maybe with a bit of XML mining to store the filename; though I doubt it.

Comment: @A T - Have tried 7-zip, but it doesn't recognize the archive... See [error message](http://imgur.com/gx542). Also, what do you mean by "XML mining"

Comment: You could try with IZarc, but I doubt it will work. No need to worry about XML mining if you can't event open the archive...

Comment: @A T - Unfortunately IZarc didn't seem to open it either (Though, by I am assuming bad design, I cannot tell as the windows just flickers and gives no error, nor no contents of the cab visible)